# How to query for datetime today

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `Appointment` model where there is a `booktime field of datetime type(postgres).`

Appointment.last has `booktime: Tue, 31 Jan 2017 05:00:00 UTC +00:00`. When I query `Appointment.where(booktime: Date.today) I get empty array []`. But **Date.today** shows `Tue, 31 Jan 2017`

I want to check Appointment model if they are any booktime for 24 hour range. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on Postgres

```
Appointment.where("date_trunc('day', booktime) = ?", Date.today)
```

Comment: You can also write this as `.where("date_trunc('day', booktime) =  current_date")`.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you don't want your code to be specific to pg, you could pass a date range:

```rb
Appointment.where(date: Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you use `Appointment.where("booktime < ? and booktime > ?", Date.today, Date.today - 1.day)` ?

Answer (score 1):

After Rails 5.1 you can use the `all_day` method, which returns the timestamp range for a given date or time:

```
Appointment.where(booktime: Date.today.all_day)
```